# List of single words being generated/parsed as multiple single-word lines in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

A colleague has asked me to help with a shell script which, among other things, generates a list of single words (usernames) from a data file and then loops through this list (as a for-loop) to run further commands for each of these usernames.

The script is not generating the expected output, and after putting in some debugging echo statements (to output the list, and the current value being processed by the for-loop, respectively), it looks (I suppose not unexpectedly, given the use of `grep`) that the list is being generated as a string of single words each separated into individual lines, rather than the one-line multi-word string that `for` needs(?).

(Oddly, some of the later output from within the for-loop does seem to use the 'current' username value as expected each time, but other parts seem to always use the first value from the list each time (presumably getting confused by the fact that the list is actually made up of multiple lines, rather than a single line with multiple values).)

The list is generated by:

```
OQLIST=`grep "*" ${QCHECK_FILE} | gawk -F " " '{print $1}'`
```

The for-loop syntax is:

```
for OQUSER in ${OQLIST}; do
    # various stuff
done
```

The script is running as `/bin/sh` (which is actually `bash` on this system). I don't *think* it has any bashisms in it, and it would probably be fine if it actually did run as `bash` if need  be.

Is there a way to get the list values into the for-loop in the way that it wants, or is there a more appropriate way to loop through these values instead?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  It should work as is, if there are no other odd separators in field 1 of the `${QCHECK_FILE}`. Is the output of `echo $OQLIST` the expected list of space separated users? How are the other parts refering to the single entry and others to the first always? Are you sure there is no mixup of `$OQLIST` and `$OQUSER` in these cases? Minor hint: it is [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/5114441) that shell-specific and environment variables are all capital, while script-specific ones are lower case -- no obligation, but common agreement.

Comment: @FelixJN I'm assuming they are expecting to loop over units consisting of lines of multiple words, not over individual words.  It won't work with a `for` loop though as their unquoted variable expansion is split on _any_ whitespace (and is subject to globbing). It would be better to pipe into a `while read` loop, or better yet, into `awk` (depending what they want to do with the data).

Comment: @they But that should be excluded with the `awk -F" " '{print $1}'` selection? And splitting a list into single users + sometimes the expected output. There is something odd here.

Comment: @FelixJN In that case they are not showing the actual code they are running. It might be that the assign data to `OQLIST` as an array (`OQLIST=( $(grep ...) )`) and then use it as a scalar (`$OQLIST`), which would give them the first element every time.  It's unclear.

Comment: @they agreed. Too little information - the problem cannot be seen in the given code snippets.

Comment: Hmm... They could also be using `zsh` unknowingly. That shell does not split unquoted variables by default. In any case, they should pipe the data into a `while` loop instead. Using a `for` loop for an indeterminate amount of data is inelegant and ineffective.

Comment: Did you by any chance set `IFS` to some non-default value earlier in the script? There's too many possibilities and not enough of a script for us to help much. Come up with a minimal, complete script and sample input/expected output demonstrating your problem. Now copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about (your posted code snippets have issues). If you still have a problem after that then post your code (after fixing what shellcheck tells you about), input and output so we can help you.